# Java: XPath get element count at same path

Tags: java, xml, xpath

How can I get element count at same path in Java? i.e:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title is here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div1">
            <table id="table1">
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>11</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>33</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table id="table2">
                <tr>
                    <td>111</td>
                    <td>222</td>
                    <td>333</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1111</td>
                    <td>2222</td>
                    <td>3333</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="div2">
            <table id="table3">
                <tr>
                    <td>11111</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

in this html,

- `/html/head/title` -> returns `"Title is here"`
- `/html/body/div[1]/table[1]/tr[2]/td[3]`   -> returns `33`
- `/html/body/div[2]/table/tr/td`            -> returns `11111`

but there are n td's in any tr, or there are m tr's in any table, or there are many table's in a document .. etc.

Is there any expression that gives me element count like count("/html/body/div[1]/table[1]/tr[2]") and it will return 3? If there is not any way to this, can i write my own helper method in Java?

Comment: Doesn't the `XPath` expression return a `NodeList` or something of the sort on which you can call `size()`, `getLength()`, etc.?

Comment: I'm really wondering same thing. I searched and did not find any way / practice.

Comment: Why not using `count()` function of xpath itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:message>All of the td's: <xsl:value-of select="count(//td)"/> </xsl:message>
    <xsl:message>All of the td's in table1: <xsl:value-of select="count(//table[@id='table1']//td)"/></xsl:message>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Produces this output:**

> [xslt] All of the td's: 13
>
> [xslt] All of the td's in table1: 6

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see `count()` before.